# Flutter localizations: Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, flutter-dependencies

I don't know why the Flutter localizations code not working with null safety.

When I check with values, I always get the null check operator used on the null value.

getTranslated causing the error.

getTranslated

This method can't return any values.

```
String? getTranslated(String key, BuildContext context) {
  return AppLocalization.of(context)?.translate(key);
}
```

app localization code handles with languages data.

error stack is

```
The following _CastError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, dependencies:
[_InheritedProviderScope<LocalizationProvider>, _InheritedProviderScope<ThemeProvider>], state:
_MyAppState#522f6):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  MyApp MyApp:file:///D:/1npcheck/np3/lib/main.dart:28:18

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _MyAppState.build (package:np_3/main.dart:77:51)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4992:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4878:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

`load()` is a future method,it will take some frame to assign data. instead of null-assertion, you can provide default value on null case while this is just string case.

```dart
 String translate(String key) {
    return _localizedValues[key]??"still empty";
  }
```

And

```
Text(getTranslated("hi", context)?? "loading",),
```

Find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety). Also check out [FutureBuilder-class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for handling future method.

Comment: but now it only shows loading not the real value inside the json file.

Comment: btw where are you calling `load`

Comment: setState()...it's outside the stateful widget class. ?? is there any other way with provider.

Comment: load is inside applocalization

Comment: btw should we have to add `ChangeNotifier` for provider and calling `notifyListner()` to update ?

Comment: yes. that's how it works.